# Related search terms at top or bottom search results?

Tags: search, search-results

I have a rich media video search with 24 results per page.
Would you put related search terms at the top of the search results, in the sidebar, or at the bottom of the search results above the pagination?

I've noticed google puts them at the bottom, bing in the sidebar and bottom, ebay and amazon both put them at the top.

Ideally having them in two places would be great however, I want to keep my pages as short as possible.

Comment: Why do you have related search terms anyway? I'm not saying don't, I'm saying look to the intended purpose of showing related terms, what need they satisfy, what problem they solve.

Comment: It helps drive more pages/visit (impressions) from a sales perspective. From a user experience it helps users find more precise search results. Ex. they may just search "widgets" and then get a terms for "widgets AB, Widgets BC, etc" which are what they were actually looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, put the related suggestions on the side.

The problem when the related suggestions are at the top is that they come before the results : the engine misses the user’s demand. I read from the beginning. So, when the page starts with the related suggestions, I say : “I ask *apples*, he proposes me *pears*. Crappy engine.”

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how obvious you want them to be.  If you want them to be really obvious, I'd put them on the top.  The least obvious would be at the bottom (because it's likely below the fold).  In between, put in the sidebar.

It also depends on what else you want to display.  I think Google puts it at the bottom because they place ads at the top and sides.

Personally, I'd avoid putting them in two places for the reason you state.